# Response is not shown on browser window after clicking Execute button in Swagger (Nodejs-Express-Mongoose)

Tags: javascript, node.js, swagger, swagger-ui

I am trying to hit the URL localhost:3000/category/list, which is a GET request.
Unfortunately I'm not getting the response in browser. The same API has been tested in Postman and got correct results.
I'm attaching the swagger config file below.

```
const swaggerJsDoc = require("swagger-jsdoc");
const swaggerUi = require("swagger-ui-express");
const dotenv = require("dotenv");
dotenv.config({ path: "config/config.env" });

const options = {
  definition: {
    openapi: "3.0.0",
    info: {
      title: "Shopp REST APIs",
      version: "1.0.0",
      description: "API Library for Shopp - Eccomerce App",
    },
    servers: [
      {
        url: `http://localhost:${process.env.PORT}`,
      },
    ],
  },
  apis: ["/home/user/Desktop/eCommerce_App/routes/*.js"],
};
const specs = swaggerJsDoc(options);
module.exports = { specs, swaggerUi };
```

Below is the route file:

```
/**
 * @swagger
 * components:
 *  schemas:
 *      Category:
 *          type: object
 *          properties:
 *              Id:
 *                  type: string
 *              name:
 *                  type: string
 *              slug:
 *                  type: string
 *              parentId:
 *                  type: string
 *
 */

/**
 * @swagger
 * /category/list/:
 *  get:
 *      summmary: Returns the list of categories and subcategories
        responses:
 *          200:
                description: Testing Get
                content:
                    application/json:
                        schema:
                            type: array
                            items:
                                $ref: '#/components/schemas/Category'
 */

router.get("/list", listCategories); // View all the categories
```

[image: Browser Window]

[image: Network Tab > Response]

Tried the docs. Issue still persists

Comment: You say you're "not getting the response in browser", but the dev tools screenshot shows a response. What is the problem then?

Comment: Please share your code where you are making the `GET` request, you may not be doing anything with the response object, [MDN Docs on Promises](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Asynchronous/Promises)

Comment: @Helen I would like to show the response within the Swagger UI

Comment: Hi @Harrison, I have already attached the code in the above so called routes code segment. Or is that middleware u are asking?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess Swagger UI doesn't render the "Responses" section because of some errors in your route annotations that result in an invalid API definition. Specifically, you should add `*` at the beginning of each line in block comments so that the formatting and indentation is consistent.

Also, there's a typo: `summmary` should be `summary`.

Try changing the route annotations as follows and see if it resolves the issue:

```
/**
 * @swagger
 * /category/list/:
 *  get:
 *      summary: Returns the list of categories and subcategories
 *      responses:
 *          200:
 *              description: Testing Get
 *              content:
 *                  application/json:
 *                      schema:
 *                          type: array
 *                          items:
 *                              $ref: '#/components/schemas/Category'
 */
```

Comment: Hey Helen! Thanks a lot! Working fine now.